# Could not find property 'ROOT_PATH' on project':app'

Tags: java, android

I import my project I got this error that could not find property 'ROOT_PATH' on project':app'
 why I got this error?
 any suggestion to solve this error.

this is my build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:1.0.0"
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    minSdkVersion = 15
    targetSdkVersion = 24
    versionCode = 1
    versionName = "1.0"
    compileSdkVersion = 24
    buildToolsVersion = "24.0.1"
    butterknifeVersion = "8.2.1"
    supportVersion = "24.1.1"
    eventbusVersion = '3.0.0'
    daggerVersion = '2.0.1'
    jsr250Version = '1.0'
    jsoupVersion = '1.8.3'
    roboelectricVersion = '3.0'
    mockitoVersion = '1.10.19'
    junitVersion = '4.12'
}
```

Comment: What is in your **settings.gradle** file?

Comment: @srayhunter in settings.gradle i just have include ':app'

Comment: if you rebuild the project does the error go away or keep happening?

Comment: @it keep happening

Comment: can bundle up your project so it can be downloaded? What version of Android Studio are you using?